# Datagrid "Addrow" in GroupItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I want to let the user add cells in a datagrid.

When i add a Row. I want to set the row to the Group.

[image]

So the "Add-Row" should be in each group.

Is there some way to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding the Row, Fill the corresponding field to the group which you need to add the new row..

```
var row = _dataSet.Tables[tableName].NewRow();
row[columnName] = "group name";
```